# How to limit a model to one record per month (Django)?

Tags: python, django, model

I want to build a simple way to track my credit score monthly. I want to be able to track the score from the three major credit agencies for each month of the year. I should only be allowed to make these entries for one month of one year. So far I have the following in my model.

```
class Score(models.Model):
    equifax_score = models.IntegerField()
    experian_score = models.IntegerField()
    transunion_score = models.IntegerField()
```

The end goal is to have an HTML table in my view that shows me my credit score month to month. I want to be able to track this in a line graph once I have enough data. Is this the best way to store this?

Answer (score 0):

Lots of variables to the success of this idea.

1) Do you know if the credit bureau data will only be your score itself? I imagine it will not be. If you hope to store the entirety of the model to accommodate the many variables of the data, rather than only the integers.

2) You will need to have a function in your views.py that splits the data down to only the integer if you are hoping to keep this information.

3) The function mentioned above should also include a timing variable that initiates your function every month. Check out this [link](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/threading.html) for some breadcrumbs.

Good luck.